# Searching for a number in an array: c#

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I need this program to search for the value someone puts into the search but I am unable to get it to do that. I as well can't get the position of the value that I am looking for. I've tried to used myarray.indexof and a few other ways I knew of how to search for the value and display the position as well but I haven't had any success with finding a way to get it to work.

This is what I last attempted.

```
int[] myArray = new int[10];
Random randnum = new Random();
        for (int index = 0; index < myArray1.Length; index++)
        {
            myArray1[index] = randnum.Next(0, 99);
            Console.Write("{0}, ",myArray1[index]);
        }
Console.WriteLine("Enter the value you are looking for in myArray");
int iSearch = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int index1 = myArray.IndexOf(iSearch);
Console.WriteLine(iSearch);
```

Essentially what I need it to do is search for someone to be able to enter a value they are searching for in the random'd array. Then it needs to search for what they are looking for in that array (I don't fully understand the use of my array.IndexOf), and then display to the user what the value they searched for is and what position it is at in the array.

Comment: you aren't adding any values to your array. `int[] myArray = new int[10];` is creating an array with ten 0's

Comment: Why don't you read an array tutorial before posting this kind of question? Read [ask]

Comment: A quick googling of "Search for number in array C#" gave me a very helpful answer to this: [http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-indexof](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-indexof).

Comment: Please see my updated answer below

Comment: And where does `iArray1` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `IndexOf()` function available for an array. You might instead want something like this:

```
int foundIndex = myArray.ToList().IndexOf(iSearch);
```

Comment: Thanks but I altered my question to be more inline with what I originally meant to be asking. There is more added to the code and a better description(I think) of what I need now.

Answer (score 0):

IndexOf for Array is available as static method:

```
int index1 = Array.IndexOf(myArray1, iSearch);
Console.WriteLine(index1);
```

The question is somewhat inconsistent, as You use myArray and myArray1 for presumably the same variable. You also do not print index1 You are looking for, that seems to be a mistake.